# Как проверить является ли процесс системным?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

Как программно можно проверить нужный мне процесс, является ли он системным ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: из вопроса не понятно, как вам надо это проверить (*программно, эзотерически или ещё как*)?

Comment: @Anatol, программно.Поправил..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если приложение запускается с правами администратора, можно воспользоваться [Restart Manager API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373646(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsTest1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        [DllImport("Rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern UInt32 RmStartSession(out UInt32 pSessionHandle, UInt32 dwSessionFlags,
            string strSessionKey);

        [DllImport("Rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern UInt32 RmRegisterResources(UInt32 dwSessionHandle,
        UInt32 nFiles, string[] rgsFilenames, UInt32 nApplications,
        ref RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS rgApplications, UInt32 nServices, string[] rgsServiceNames);

        [DllImport("Rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern UInt32 RmGetList(UInt32 dwSessionHandle, out UInt32 pnProcInfoNeeded,
        ref UInt32 pnProcInfo, [In, Out] RM_PROCESS_INFO[] rgAffectedApps, ref UInt32 lpdwRebootReasons);

        [DllImport("Rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern UInt32 RmEndSession(UInt32 dwSessionHandle);

        public const UInt32 RmRebootReasonNone = 0x0;
        public const int ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;

        /// <summary>
        /// Преобразование DateTime в структуру FILETIME 
        /// </summary>        
        public static System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME FileTimeFromDateTime(DateTime date)
        {
            long ftime = date.ToFileTime();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ft = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME();
            ft.dwHighDateTime = (int)(ftime >> 32);
            ft.dwLowDateTime = (int)ftime;
            return ft;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Получение типа процесса
        /// </summary>        
        public static RM_APP_TYPE GetProcessType(Process proc)
        {
            uint handle;
            string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();            

            uint res = RmStartSession(out handle, (uint)0, key);
            if (res != 0)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Could not begin restart session. ");
            }

            try
            {                
                uint pnProcInfoNeeded = 0, pnProcInfo = 0,
                    lpdwRebootReasons = RmRebootReasonNone;

                RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS uniqueprocess = new RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS();
                uniqueprocess.dwProcessId = proc.Id;
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ft = FileTimeFromDateTime(proc.StartTime);
                uniqueprocess.ProcessStartTime = ft;

                res = RmRegisterResources(handle, 0, null, 1, ref uniqueprocess, 0, null);

                if (res != 0)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Could not register resource.");
                }

                res = RmGetList(handle, out pnProcInfoNeeded, ref pnProcInfo, null,
                                ref lpdwRebootReasons);
                if (res == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
                {
                    RM_PROCESS_INFO[] processInfo = new RM_PROCESS_INFO[pnProcInfoNeeded];
                    pnProcInfo = pnProcInfoNeeded;

                    // Get the list. 
                    res = RmGetList(handle, out pnProcInfoNeeded, ref pnProcInfo,
                        processInfo, ref lpdwRebootReasons);
                    if (res == 0)
                    {
                        if (pnProcInfo == 0) throw new ApplicationException("Process not found");

                        return processInfo[0].ApplicationType;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("Could not list processes");
                    }
                }
                else if (res != 0)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Failed to get size of result.");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                RmEndSession(handle);
            }
            throw new ApplicationException("Process not found");
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                
        }               


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //пример использования                            
            Process p=Process.GetProcessesByName(textBox1.Text)[0];
            MessageBox.Show(GetProcessType(p).ToString());
            /*Для системных процессов выведет RmCritical*/
        }        
    }

    /* Определения структур */

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS
    {
        // The product identifier (PID). 
        public int dwProcessId;
        // The creation time of the process. 
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ProcessStartTime;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct RM_PROCESS_INFO
    {
        const int CCH_RM_MAX_APP_NAME = 255;
        const int CCH_RM_MAX_SVC_NAME = 63;

        // Contains an RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS structure that uniquely identifies the 
        // application by its PID and the time the process began. 
        public RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS Process;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCH_RM_MAX_APP_NAME + 1)]
        // If the process is a service, this parameter returns the  
        // long name for the service. 
        public string strAppName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCH_RM_MAX_SVC_NAME + 1)]
        // If the process is a service, this is the short name for the service. 
        public string strServiceShortName;
        // Contains an RM_APP_TYPE enumeration value. 
        public RM_APP_TYPE ApplicationType;
        // Contains a bit mask that describes the current status of the application. 
        public uint AppStatus;
        // Contains the Terminal Services session ID of the process. 
        public uint TSSessionId;
        // TRUE if the application can be restarted by the  
        // Restart Manager; otherwise, FALSE. 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public bool bRestartable;
    }

    public enum RM_APP_TYPE
    {
        // The application cannot be classified as any other type. 
        RmUnknownApp = 0,
        // A Windows application run as a stand-alone process that 
        // displays a top-level window. 
        RmMainWindow = 1,
        // A Windows application that does not run as a stand-alone 
        // process and does not display a top-level window. 
        RmOtherWindow = 2,
        // The application is a Windows service. 
        RmService = 3,
        // The application is Windows Explorer. 
        RmExplorer = 4,
        // The application is a stand-alone console application. 
        RmConsole = 5,
        // A system restart is required to complete the installation because 
        // a process cannot be shut down. 
        RmCritical = 1000
    }
}
```

Код основан на данном примере: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-know-the-process-704839f4

Метод `GetProcessType` возвращает тип процесса, для системных процессов он равен значению `RM_APP_TYPE.RmCritical`.

Если приложение не имеет прав администратора, все проще: попытка получить дескриптор системного процесса просто упадет с ошибкой "Отказано в доступе". Нужно лишь ловить `Win32Exception`.

---

**Другие способы**

С использованием (нерекомендуемой) функции [NtQueryInformationProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) из Native API:

```
const uint ProcessBreakOnTermination = 29;

[DllImport("NTDLL.DLL")]
static extern int NtQueryInformationProcess(IntPtr hProcess, uint pic,
ref uint pi, int cb, out int pSize);

public static bool IsProcessCritical(Process pr)
{

    uint val = 0;
    int size;
    int res = NtQueryInformationProcess(pr.Handle, ProcessBreakOnTermination, ref val,
        sizeof(uint), out size);
    if (res != 0 || size != sizeof(uint)) throw new Win32Exception("NtQueryInformationProcess failed");

    return (val != 0);
}
```

Начиная с Windows 8.1 можно использовать функцию [IsProcessCritical](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn386160%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/831381/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-ntdll-dll).

Answer (score 9):

Если вы откроете диспетчер задач, то увидите владельца процесса => следуя этому [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777548/how-do-i-determine-the-owner-of-a-process-in-c)

Можно получить владельца процесса через WMI:

```
public string GetProcessOwner(int processId)
{
    string query = "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " + processId;
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
    {
        string[] argList = new string[] { string.Empty, string.Empty };
        int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));
        if (returnVal == 0)
        {
            // return DOMAIN\user
            return argList[1] + "\\" + argList[0];
        }
    }

    return "NO OWNER";
}

public string GetProcessOwner(string processName)
{
    string query = "Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = \"" + processName + "\"";
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
    {
        string[] argList = new string[] { string.Empty, string.Empty };
        int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));
        if (returnVal == 0)
        {
            // return DOMAIN\user
            string owner = argList[1] + "\\" + argList[0];
            return owner;       
        }
    }

    return "NO OWNER";
}
```

Это более лучшее решение, чем явно перечислять системные процессы, которые могут добавлять при установке спец. компонентов=> список составить тяжело.

Как меня поправляют в комментариях, есть еще всякие сервисы, где отсутствует учетка, так же есть некотые системные учетки, например MS SQL работает из специфичной учетки, если я не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Ну дополняйте тогда уж ответ, что есть система, есть локальные сервисы и собственно пользователь. Процессы системы лучше не трогать, локальные можно, пользовательские судя по вопросу - нужно.

Comment: @Monk для информации: то, что у процесса владелец SYSTEM, далеко не всегда значит, что его "лучше не трогать". Если на то пошло, любую службу можно настроить на запуск из-под SYSTEM, например у меня SQL Server VSS Writer так настроен, но он не является системным процессом (его вполне можно завершить без завершения системы)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight но таки молча завершать процессы, которые запущены по системой - очень подозрительное поведение. Сомневаюсь, что вы будете рады, если этот самый SQL Server VSS Writer умрёт от запуска какого то приложения.

Answer (score 6):

Начнем с того, что у нас будет какая-то информация о процессах (не забываем подключить пространство имен `using System.Diagnostics;`):

```
Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process process in processList)
{
    // В process хранится информация о процессе
}
```

Метод [`GetProcesses`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses(v=vs.110).aspx) - возвращает массив компонентов `Process` для каждого ресурса процесса на локальном компьютере. Собственно, у процесса [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) есть свойство `Id` в котором находится уникальный идентификатор связанного процесса.

После выполнения этого кода у нас есть данные о процессах, и можно перейти к другой части, получение описания процесса и владельца процесса.

Добавим ссылку на сборку `System.Management` кликаем на проекте, затем через <kbd>Add</kbd>-><kbd>Reference...</kbd> ставим галочку и прописываем `using System.Management;`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Напишем такой метод:

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetProcessExtraInformation(int processId)
{
    // запрос получения всех процессов связанных с переданным идентификатором processId
    string query = "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " + processId;
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get();

    // здесь будет результат    
    List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> result = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

    foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
    {
        var description = @"Не могу получить информацию о процессе";
        // Получим описание процесса, если таковое имеется
        if (obj["ExecutablePath"] != null)
        {
            try
            {
                FileVersionInfo info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(obj["ExecutablePath"].ToString());
                description = info.FileDescription;
            }
            catch { }
        }

        // Получить владельца процесса в argList 
        var owner = @"Не могу получить владельца процесса";
        string[] argList = new string[] { string.Empty, string.Empty };
        int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));
        if (returnVal == 0)
        {
            owner = argList[1] + "\\" + argList[0]; // Домен и владелец                    
        }

        result.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(processId, string.Format("Description: '{0}'\nOwner: '{1}'", description, owner)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Да, начальный код перепишем вот так:

```
Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process process in processList)
{
    // В process хранится информация о процессе
    var processInfo = GetProcessExtraInformation(process.Id);

    foreach (var info in processInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Id: {0}\n{1}", info.Key, info.Value));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

В результате получим что-то на подобии вот этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модернизировал ответ из источника: [How do I determine the owner of a process in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/777567/5275890) и дополнил некоторыми деталями результат. Исходя из полученных данных, можно предположить, что процесс с владельцем **SYSTEM** - является системным процессом. Также, следует обратить внимание на домены.

> Учетная запись локальной системы — это встроенная учетная запись,
>   обладающая очень высокими правами доступа. Она имеет обширные права и
>   выступает в качестве компьютера сети. Фактическое имя этой учетной
>   записи — «**NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM**».

Про учетные записи и службы можно почитать к примеру здесь: [Настройка учетных записей служб Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms143504(v=sql.100).aspx) в разделе *Использование стартовых учетных записей для запуска служб SQL Server*

Answer (score 4):

Если я не ошибаюсь нет явного способа опеределить, является ли процесс системным, зато можно сделать список системных процессов и проверять вхождение.

Вот список навскидку:

```
List<string> sp = new List<string>
{
    "svchost", "csrss", "System", "wininit",
    "irstrtsv","scrncap","lsass","System",
    "wininit","taskmgr","dwm","spoolsv","smss",
    "SearchIndexer","lsm","taskhost","svchost","explorer",
    "winlogon","services","conhost"
};
```

Comment: а если это MacOS? :)

Comment: @Nick Proskuryakov, Делаю по этому принципу, обход всех системных процессов и завершение не нужных. Но думал сделать доп проверку если другой процесс является системным ( не из списка List<>), то не трогать его.

Comment: @GooliveR ничего больше не могу посоветовать, только держать список системных параметров в актуальном состоянии)

Comment: Ох, ну а devenv-то как в список системных процессов попал? Да и explorer и conhost не настолько системные...