# Не найдена функция из ntdll.dll

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Есть следующий код:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IntPtr handle = OpenProcess(0x1000, false, 1020);
        bool isp;
        IsProcessCritical(handle, out isp);
        Console.WriteLine(isp);

        CloseHandle(handle);
    }

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
    public static extern bool IsProcessCritical(IntPtr h, out bool b);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess,
        bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle);
```

на строчке IsProcessCritical(handle, out isp) происходит следующее:

> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Не удается найти точку входа "IsProcessCritical" в DLL "ntdll.dll".'

функция взята из MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dn386160(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
BOOL WINAPI IsProcessCritical(
_In_  HANDLE hProcess,
_Out_ PBOOL  Critical
);
```

расположена: Ntdll.dll

Есть идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
 public static extern bool IsProcessCritical(IntPtr h, out bool b);
```

Comment: работать начало, только как-то странно: при проверке процессов csrss.exe, services.exe, smss.exe возвращается False, хотя если завершить один из этих процессов - будет BSOD с кодом CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED.

Comment: Может у Вас доступа нет, может что то ещё. Угадать не смогу. Приводите полный код и спросите другим вопросом. Потому что как импортировать эту функцию Вы уже знаете.

Comment: так это и есть полный код. сейчас попробую от имени администратора запустить

Comment: вы были правы насчет прав. надо проверять GetLastError для избежания недоразумений.

Comment: OpenProcess что возвращает ? Проверку поставьте. Может там NULL

Comment: тут была проблема с IsCriticalProcess, OpenProcess возвращает правильно, потому что dwDesiredAccess = 0x1000, т.е PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION (как и в MSDN)